# How to return a changable value for Discordia-slash file

Tags: lua, discord, discord-interactions, luvit

So this question is a complicated one, but i'll try to explain it as much understandable as possible.
I am using Discordia to make a discord bot and Discordia-slash to apply a slash-commands ("/").
Then i desided to make 2 separated files, one with commands list and applying them and one with all other bot thing, and i made this

```lua
local discordia = require('discordia')
local tools = require('discordia-slash').util.tools()
Commands = {}

function Commands.apply()
    local SlashCommand = {}
    for group, commanddata in pairs(Cmd) do
       table.insert(SlashCommand, {
        name = commanddata["назва"],
        description  = commanddata["опис"],
        type = 1,
       })
       if commanddata["опції"] then
            for numeric, optiondata in pairs(commanddata["опції"]) do
                for command, value in pairs(SlashCommand) do

                
                
                SlashCommand[command].options = {
                    name = optiondata["назва"],
                    description = optiondata["опис"],
                    type = optiondata["тип"]
                }
                
                end
            end
       end
       
       
    end
    for i, v in pairs(SlashCommand) do
        for i2, v2 in pairs(v) do
            print(i, i2, v2)
        end
        return SlashCommand[i]
    end
end
return Commands
```

That function makes a ready to use Commands list like

```lua
SlashCommand = {
{
   name = ...,
   description = ...,
   options = {...}
},
{
   name  = ...,
   description = ...,
}
```

and i have this in my **main** file:

```lua
CLIENT:on("ready", function()
  -- you'll have to load application commands into discord first in order to use them.
  -- however, after loading once, you don't have to load them everytime your bot loads.
  -- gets a list of registered application commands from discord bot
  local commands = CLIENT:getGlobalApplicationCommands()
  -- deletes any existing application command from the bot's commands list
  for commandId in pairs(commands) do
    CLIENT:deleteGlobalApplicationCommand(commandId)
  end
  -- register application commands into the bot's commands
  CLIENT:info("готово до використання")
  print("Активовано: ".. CLIENT.user.tag)

end)
```

and my Commands.apply() function should return commands from it's SlashCommand list in row, to apply them all.
How to do that, because it's not working with return.